# mvn build failing with xray

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, aws-xray

I am trying  funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts. I wanted to try XRay support and added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-xray</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But getting errors like below when building project. I am sure there is some configuration I am missing. I tried searching docs at Quarkus but no success.

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] docker run -v /Users/jay/dev/java-lambda/quarkus-quickstarts/funqy-quickstarts/funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart/target/funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --env LANG=C --rm quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:20.1.0-java11 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -jar funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:-IncludeAllTimeZones -H:EnableURLProtocols=http --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
-H:IncludeAllTimeZones and -H:IncludeTimeZones are now deprecated. Native-image includes all timezonesby default.
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]    classlist:   9,874.79 ms,  0.94 GB
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]        (cap):   1,127.41 ms,  0.94 GB
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]        setup:   3,086.63 ms,  0.94 GB
11:32:19,929 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]     (clinit):     796.70 ms,  1.11 GB
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]   (typeflow):  16,029.95 ms,  1.11 GB
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]    (objects):  25,406.30 ms,  1.11 GB
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]   (features):     698.70 ms,  1.11 GB
[funqy-amazon-lambda-http-quickstart-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:24]     analysis:  45,576.08 ms,  1.11 GB
Error: Unsupported features in 18 methods
Detailed message:
Error: Class initialization of com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRayRecorderBuilder failed. Use the option --initialize-at-run-time=com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRayRecorderBuilder to explicitly request delayed initialization of this class.
Original exception that caused the problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRayRecorderBuilder.<clinit>(AWSXRayRecorderBuilder.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1042)
        at jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:698)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.ensureClassInitialized(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:169)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:586)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:132)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.maybeInitializeHosted(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:160)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.registerType(SVMHost.java:223)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:264)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X-Ray SDK uses the Apache commons logging library to emit log messages. It takes this dependency transitively from the AWS SDK. I'm not familiar with the `quarkus` library, but the only reason that I can think of that would cause this error is if a `pom.xml` somewhere is explicitly excluding the Apache commons logging library from being pulled in transitively. The remedy that should work is to add the dependency to your classpath manually:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying get my head around GraalVM and Quarkus.